# Looking for best match solution on searching function on listview

Tags: android

i wanted to add a search function to my customize list view. i actually search through internet for few hours, but i unable to follow all those complicated tutorial or demo, so i decided to post my problem here. Hope somebody can actually help me to solve this. here is my code

```
    ListView lv;
    EditText inputSearch;
    CustomListView testingAdapter;
    //at oncreate method
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEditSavingList);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    loadListViewData();

    private void loadListViewData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UnderControlDb db = new UnderControlDb(getApplicationContext());
    String[] info = db.MySavingShowData();
    int counter = info.length;
    Integer[] imageID = new Integer[counter];
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
        imageID[i] = R.drawable.edit_notes_list;
    }
    testingAdapter = new CustomListView(MySaving.this, info, imageID);
    lv.setAdapter(testingAdapter);
}
```

then this is my customize class

```
public class CustomListView extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Activity context;
private final String[] data;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomListView(Activity context,String[] data, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.my_saving_list, data);
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_saving_list, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSavingListView);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgS);
    txtTitle.setText(data[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
}
```

}

and my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSavingListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgS"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a small sample in order to show you how you can search data from your listView.
Find below the code, and do not hesitate to ask me any question for more clarification.

```
public class TestSearch extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    EditText inputSearch;
    CustomListView testingAdapter;

    public class listContent{
        public String info;
        public int imageInfo;

        public listContent(String info, int imageInfo) {
            this.info = info;
            this.imageInfo = imageInfo;
        }
        public String getInfo() {
            return info;
        }
        public void setInfo(String info) {
            this.info = info;
        }
        public int getImageInfo() {
            return imageInfo;
        }
        public void setImageInfo(int imageInfo) {
            this.imageInfo = imageInfo;
        }

    }

    ArrayList<listContent> itemsContent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_search);
        itemsContent = new ArrayList<listContent>();
        CustomListView testingAdapter;
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEditSavingList);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        loadListViewData();
    }
    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = inputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            testingAdapter.filter(text);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) { 
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }
    };
    private void loadListViewData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        itemsContent.add(new listContent("text", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        itemsContent.add(new listContent("hello", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        itemsContent.add(new listContent("dear", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        itemsContent.add(new listContent("test", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        itemsContent.add(new listContent("lol", R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        testingAdapter = new CustomListView(TestSearch.this, itemsContent);
        lv.setAdapter(testingAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_search, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public class CustomListView extends BaseAdapter{
        private final Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<listContent> items;
        ArrayList<listContent> filtereditems;

        public CustomListView(Context context, ArrayList<listContent> items) {
            this.mContext= context;
            this.items = items;
            this.filtereditems = new ArrayList<listContent>();
            this.filtereditems.addAll(items);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_saving_list, null, true);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSavingListView);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgS);
            txtTitle.setText(items.get(position).getInfo());
            imageView.setImageResource(items.get(position).getImageInfo());
            return rowView;
        }

        public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            items.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                items.addAll(filtereditems);
            } 
            else
            {
                for (listContent wp : filtereditems) 
                {
                    if(wp.getInfo().startsWith(charText))
                    {
                        items.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return items.get(arg0);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your effort

but it still a litter bit complicated for me
but i found something another 1 method to do and i actually followed this method 
http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com/2012/04/search-custom-listview-in-android.html#comment-form